# Most performant way to run Ubuntu VM on Windows 10 with hyper-v enabled?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, performance

I get sluggish results with Ubuntu in hyper-v.
VirtualBox 6.1.16 seems faster (60 FPS almost), but still not fluid.

Is there some guideline how to configure the Ubuntu/Linux virtual machine with hyper-v enabled for maximum performance? I need hyper-v and I want to have Ubuntu with GUI for development purposes.

My configuration:

```
Processor(s): 12 Cores (AMD Ryzen 9 3900X) 
RAM:24 GB 
Guest addition installed on VM
Graphics controller: VMSVGA 
Enable PAE/NX: check
Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V (not possible to check, control is grayed out)
Hardware Virtualization: Enable Nested Paging: check
```

glxgears performance counters:
`56 FPS`

Subjective feeling: dragging a `konsole` window is slow, user feels the input latency. I use Kubuntu derivate.

Comment: Is the machine on an SSD or Hard Drive.  Ubuntu 20 in VMware Workstation, 3 GB of memory, 2 cores, and on an SSD drive is very smooth. So is my Kali machine. SSD drive is one of the best ways to make a Virtual Machine perform well.

Comment: Yes, it is. I think the difference is VMWare Workstation then I guess. Probably it has better graphics driver then what VirtualBox and Windows Hyper-V-enabled environment provides.